# FirstRun do programa startup form é uma e depois do firstrun a startup form muda vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Preciso de ajuda, eu tenho um jogo em vb.net em que eu quero que no firstrun do programa abra um form que dá para por o nick e tem um mini tutorial etc, e depois da firstrun a startup form muda para o jogo, sem aparecer o form para por o nick.

Já tentei fazer:

```
    Private Sub Inicio_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Settings.FirstRun = True Then
            My.Settings.FirstRun = False
            My.Settings.Save()
        ElseIf My.Settings.FirstRun = False Then
            Dim Inicio As Inicio
                Inicio = New Inicio
            Inicio.Hide()
            Dim Form1 As Form1
            Form1 = New Form1
            Form1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
  End Class
```

Mas a form principal (Inicio) aparece junto com a Form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguinte, para isso funcionar, o correto é verificar isso ao iniciar o sistema antes de dar load em qualquer form que seja. Para fazer isso primeiramente deve-se criar na raiz do seu projeto uma classe de inicialização desta forma:

```
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

        If (My.Settings.FirstRun) Then
            My.Settings.FirstRun = False
            My.Settings.Save()
            Application.Run(New Form1) 'aqui seria seu form para inserir o usuário e senha
        Else
            Application.Run(New Form2) 'aqui seria seu form Inicio
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Em seguida, nas configurações de seu projeto, desmarque esta opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E mude a opção **Startup object** para a nova classe que você criou ***(no caso a minha chamava Program)***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto, agora rode o projeto e veja que antes de mostrar qualquer form, o sistema passará por esta classe, assim, você consegue interceptar e mostrar o form que quiser.

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida só perguntar.

Abraço!